# insert a new record just after a old record in a database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is this possible?

eg:

```
record1
record2
record3
```

I want to insert `record4` just after `record1`.

Comment: The placement of a row in a database has no importance. There is no need for this.

Comment: What language are you using?  I assume by the tag that it is mysql.  Are you trying to insert a record into a list vs. adding it to the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A database table (i'm assuming a *relational* database table) represents an unordered set of records. There being no order, there is not a concept of "after". So no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

To add to **abl**'s correct answer, if you actually want "record 4" to appear after "record 1" and there is a way that it can, then you need to apply an ORDER BY statement to your SELECT query, and potentially use an INDEX to aid efficiency.

eg: If all your records contain a numeric "Employee ID", and you insert 4 records as follows:

Rec#1: 1234  Fred Smith
Rec#2: 1240  Alice Bloggs
Rec#3: 1260  Bill Brice
Rec#4: 1239  Emma Gibbs

then while the database "stores" them this way, without some additional instruction (eg: ORDER BY), SQL does not even guarantee to return them in this order!

So

```
SELECT EmpID, EmpName FROM EmpTable
```

could give you these for records in potentially any order each time you run the command. 
In practice, and without adding or changing these records, you are likely to see the same order returned each time, ***but you cannot count on it!***

To get back the records in EmpID order, use:

```
SELECT EmpID, EmpName FROM EmpTable ORDER BY EmpID
```

If you have a large number of records, add an index to aid performance.
(Although, this should exist anyway to ensure uniqueness of the Primary Key (EmpID) - ie: ensuring you can't have two Employees with the same ID.)